# Make interactive graph of count history in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, graph

I have the following code for a counter with two buttons, one to increase the count and the other to decrease it. The count is a label containing a number. The graph that appears with the buttons is supposed to visualise the history of the counted number ie. x axis is the index number of results_table and the y axis is the number that appears in the count. The buttons and the count work but the graph doesn't show with the following code. There is obviously something I am missing to get the graph to update. Here's the code:

```
    import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Create a container
        frame = tkinter.Frame(master)
        # Create 2 buttons
        self.button_left = tkinter.Button(frame,text="-", command=self.decrease, bg = 'red', fg = 'white')
        self.button_left.pack(side="left")
        self.button_right = tkinter.Button(frame,text="+", command=self.increase, bg = 'green', fg = 'white')
        self.button_right.pack(side="right")
        
        self.label_value = tk.Label(frame, text = '0')
        self.label_value.pack(side = "bottom")

        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = ax.plot(0)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
        frame.pack()
        
        result_table = []

    def decrease(self):
        value = int(self.label_value["text"])
        self.label_value["text"] = f"{value - 1}"
        result_table.append(self.label_value['text'])
        x, y = self.line.get_data('result_table')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def increase(self):
        value = int(self.label_value["text"])
        self.label_value["text"] = f"{value + 1}"
        result_table.append(self.label_value['text'])
        x, y = self.line.get_data('result_table')
        self.canvas.draw()

root = tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Any help graetly appreciated.
Matt

Comment: You don't seem to do anything with `x` and `y` values except assign values to them

Comment: What have you done to debug this? For example, have you verified that the expected data is being passed to the function that draws the figure?

Comment: Yes. I can print the result table. What I’m not sure about is how to assign the index and the count number to the axis of the graph. I believe the problem lies in that area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I solved your problem, but it is not a straight forward answer/solution.
First of all you designed your GUI quiet good! I just wouldn't use `pack()` but I prefer `grid()`.
Next, I had to delete your class, because I never used tkinter with a class. Maybe you will be able to put it back in.

So what I did:
As already mentioned by Matiiss, you don't really use your `x` and `y` values to plot your figure. Your `result_table` on the other hand just works fine and stores all values created!
So you have to plot them as `y` values and your `x` values are basically dependent on the length of your result_table `len(result_table)`. For this part I used numpy to always generate an array of the appropriate length.

Furthermore, I created an extra container `fig_frame` inside the root, where I always display the figure.

This code worked for me:

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np


def decrease():
    value = int(label_value["text"])
    label_value["text"] = f"{value - 1}"
    result_table.append(label_value['text'])
    x = np.arange(len(result_table))
    y = result_table
    create_fig(x, y)


def increase():
    value = int(label_value["text"])
    label_value["text"] = f"{value + 1}"
    result_table.append(label_value['text'])
    x = np.arange(len(result_table))
    y = result_table
    create_fig(x, y)


def create_fig(x, y):
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    line, = ax.plot(x, y)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, fig_frame)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)


root = tk.Tk()
# Create a container
frame = tk.Frame(root)
fig_frame = tk.Canvas(root, height=650, width=650, borderwidth=1, relief='ridge')
fig_frame.pack()

# Create 2 buttons
button_left = tk.Button(frame, text="-", command=decrease, bg='red', fg='white')
button_left.pack(side="left")
button_right = tk.Button(frame, text="+", command=increase, bg='green', fg='white')
button_right.pack(side="right")

label_value = tk.Label(frame, text='0')
label_value.pack(side="bottom")

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot(0)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, fig_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)
frame.pack()

result_table = []

root.mainloop()
```

Keep going like this! You really already did a great work and even if my code looks different to your code, most parts are just rearranged!

Comment: Ok I just found out, that it doesn't work perfectly and your y axis is getting weird if you go to negative values, but I am sure you can solve this one on your own :)

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for that, I'll look into the problem you mention with the axis. More mind bending fun!

Comment: Finally to put this to rest I presumed that the problem with the y axis was because the graph essentially plots a list, therefore each new value was being added as a new string rather than in numerical order. Replace y = (result_table) with y = list(map(int, result_table)) to replace the strings with integers and it works beautifully> Thanks again for all your help. Great job and keep up the good work